# Why my loop isn't working?

Tags: php, loop

I am using this loop and instead of getting my posts(blogs) i am getting pagetitle in my case Home and Homepage content

```
<?php
while(have_posts()) {
    the_post(); ?>
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
    <hr>
 <?php }
?>
```

[image: What i am trying to get]

[image: This is what i have for now]

Comment: Where are you using this code? Is it in a template file, `functions.php`, a plugin,...? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/345294/edit) to provide more context.

Comment: That is the main query, and it is for that specific page. You will need to build a different query and loop to display something else.

Comment: There is no query argument, you don't set up the query correctly. Google for $args of the query. In addition, I'd add an if statement if(have_posts()).. while... there are hundrets of examples on this site and on the web.

Comment: I am trying to make my own theme i made an index.php and i want to try this loop but didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do with this.

Out of the Box, WordPres allows you to set your home page as either a static page, or a blog. If you choose blog, it will automatically output title and content for you.

If you're trying to customize a static home page, then you'll need to add a piece with arguments, like they've been saying there in the comments.

```
    <?php   
    $args = [
            'post_type'      => 'posts', // you can also use custom post types here
            'posts_per_page' => '10', // how many I want to display
            'post_status'    => 'publish', // I only want published posts to appear

        ];

    // The Query.
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop.
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post(); 
    } ?>

    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <hr>

    <?php endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    ?>
```